# How to find a string using pattern in java

Tags: java

please refer below code

```
    String line = "abc_dfgb_tf";

    String pattern1 = "(\\w+)([+-])(\\d+)(\\w+)";
    Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
    Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(line);

    if (m1.find( )) 
    {
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(1) );
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(2) );
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(3) );
       System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(4) );
    }
```

in case of "abc_dfgb_tf" string m1.find( ) is coming false.

please suggest the pattern which will use for both type of string "abc_dfgb_tf" and "abc_dfgb_tf+1cbv"

help

Comment: Just make the `[+-]` part optional: `[+-]?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want optional everything except the first group. Something like

```
String line = "abc_dfgb_tf";
String pattern1 = "(\\w+)([+-]*)(\\d*)(\\w*)";
Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(line);

if (m1.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(1));
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(2));
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(3));
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(4));
}
```

Output is

```
Found value: abc_dfgb_tf
Found value: 
Found value: 
Found value:
```

and if I change line to `String line = "abc_dfgb_tf+1cbv";` output is

```
Found value: abc_dfgb_tf
Found value: +
Found value: 1
Found value: cbv
```

Comment: got it .. Thnaks :) Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 5):

You appear to want something like this:

```
String pattern1 = "(\\w+)(?:([+-])(\\d+)(\\w+))?";
```

That makes the optional tail in fact optional.

Comment: got it .. Thnaks :) John Bollinger